# Check if template parameter is equal to Base class of another template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a class like this :

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class A
{
    //Error if Base class of T2 is not T1 (At compile time)
};
```

I want to check if `T1` is  Base class of `T2` . Is is possible at compile time ?

Some Examples :

```
class C{};
class B :public C{};

A< C, B > a;     //Ok because C is base class of B
A<B, C> b;       //Error B is not base class of C
A<char, char> c; //Error char is not base class of char 
//.....
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of + http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) will get you most of the way there, but it's not quite what you want. You also want an error if the two types are the same, and `is_base_of<T, T>::value` is always `true` for any user defined type `T`. Combine the check with [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to get the behavior you want.

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class A
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<T1, T2>::value &&
                  !std::is_same<T1, T2>::value,
                  "T1 must be a base class of T2");
};
```

This will result in the following:

```
A< C, B > a;     //Ok because C is base class of B
A<B, C> b;       //Error B is not base class of C
A<char, char> c; //Error char is not base class of char 
A<B, B> d;       //Error B is not base class of B <-- this won't fail without
                 //                                   the is_same check
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::is_base_of` with `std::enable_if`:

```
template <
    class T1,
    class T2,
    class = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<T1, T2>::value
    >::type
>
class A
{
};
```

You can also use `static_assert` for a custom message:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class A
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<T1, T2>::value,
                  "T1 must be a base class of T2");
};
```